# Arduino button on and off function

Tags: button, arduino

I need help for a button in Arduino to turn on and off. I am trying to make my own Arduino car for my classes in my tech lesson.

It is a transistor circuit in a connected to 2 motors, an Arduino board and an Arduino sensor shield v5.0. The code I typed in worked for an on/off function but it wouldn't turn off it only stayed on forever.

Code for the first one:

```
//variables
int led = 13; //led on indicator
int motor1 = 12; //right motor
int motor2 = 11; //left motor
int button = A0; //on and off button
int val = 0; //value for on press button

void setup() {
  //setting up code to definition of pins
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //looping the code to execute
  //button code for on and off
  val = digitalRead(button);
  if (val == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    start_driving();
    Serial.println("Turned on!");
    Serial.println("It is driving!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not turned on!");
  }
}

//functions
void start_driving() {
  //The driving function
  digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  turn_left();
  digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  turn_right();
  digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}

//turn right
void turn_right() {
  //turning right at 90 degrees
  digitalWrite(motor1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(motor1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
  delay(78);
}

//turn left
void turn_left() {
  //turning left a 90 degrees
  digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(motor1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
  delay(78);
}
```

And now I am making a new .ino file to start again (I have still kept the first one still), but I am trying to make a button on and off function to turn on the led and also activate a void function called

```
void start_driving() {
}
```

So I hope you get what I mean and I hoped that I made sense. Oh and you can help me solve the driving function if you want to as well, like help me with the turning right or left or go forward or backwards function. So can you please help me please?

Comment: Do you use Pulldowns?

Comment: "So can you please help me please?". It is sufficient to post a question. You don't have to beg for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't stop is easy: You never told them to stop. In the case that you turn off the Button it will finish the `start_driving()` function and the last commands are HIGH for the Motors. The rest of the time it will stay in the else-part of the `loop()` function and is never told to be LOW.
So add some `digitalWrite(motor1/2, LOW);` to the `start_driving()` function in the end, or in the else part of the `loop()` else.

I made some changes to your code and added the needed parts (LED has the same problems like your Motors):

```
#define LEDPIN          13        // Use defines, because the values won't change anyway
                                  // For the same reason they are Uppercase like LOW, HIGH, INPUT ...
                                  // It is an indicator for non changeing values
#define RIGHTMOTORPIN   11        // Changed to PWM capable Pins, so you can 
#define LEFTMOTORPIN    10        // have a variable speed later on
#define BUTTONPIN       A0

#define RIGHT           0         // For more readability in the makeTurn function
#define LEFT            1

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RIGHTMOTORPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEFTMOTORPIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(BUTTONPIN) == LOW){
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Turned on!");             // Put it in front, so it isn't shown after the drive
    Serial.println("It is driving!");
    startDriving();
  }else{
    Serial.println("Not turned on!");
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);                // I guess the led should be turned off too.
    parallelMotorControl(LOW);                // THIS is the reason, why it continued driving!
                                              // You never stopped the Motors
  }
}

void startDriving() {
  parallelMotorControl(HIGH);
  delay(500);
  makeTurn(RIGHT);
  parallelMotorControl(HIGH);
  delay(500);
  makeTurn(LEFT);
  parallelMotorControl(HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}

// Reuse more code, that is similar.
void makeTurn(bool turnDirection){
  if(turnDirection){                          // Right turn
    digitalWrite(RIGHTMOTORPIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEFTMOTORPIN, HIGH);
  }else{                                      // Left turn
    digitalWrite(RIGHTMOTORPIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LEFTMOTORPIN, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
  parallelMotorControl(LOW);
  delay(78);
}

void parallelMotorControl(bool motorState){
  digitalWrite(RIGHTMOTORPIN, motorState);
  digitalWrite(LEFTMOTORPIN, motorState);
}
```